# Issue with if statement in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am trying to generate LOAD DATA IN statements for all text files in a directory to one single output file. The files are delimited by either a | or a TAB, so I decided to test each file with a head -1 $file command to see whether it contains a | and output the correct load in, but it is not running. The case statements run fine without the if statements, so I have narrowed it down to the if statement. Is this the correct syntax for the a nested if statement ?

```
 #!/bin/bash


    for file in *.txt

    do

    case $file in

    *_TEST1_*)

    firstLine=`head -1 $file`;

    if [[ $firstLine =~ "|" ]]
    then
    echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Data/"$file"' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;" >> output.txt;;
    else
    echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Data/"$file"' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;" >> output.txt;;
    fi

    *_TEST2_*)
    echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Data/ "$file"' INTO TABLE testtable2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;" >> output.txt;;

    esac
    done
```

**update**

Working now, please see my answer below if you run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the placement of the double semi colons, since the double semi colons are used to specify the end of the case statement, the case statement was being closed before the if statement. I changed it to this, and now it works:

```
#!/bin/bash


    for file in *.txt

    do

    case $file in

    *_TEST1_*)

    firstLine=`head -1 $file`;

    if [[ $firstLine =~ \| ]]
    then
    echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Data/"$file"' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;" >> output.txt;
    else
    echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Data/"$file"' INTO TABLE testtable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;" >> output.txt;
    fi
```

;;

```
    *_TEST2_*)
    echo "LOAD DATA INFILE '/Data/ "$file"' INTO TABLE testtable2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ignore 1 lines;" >> output.txt
```

;;

```
    esac
    done
```